# Bloomberg Open API, client server architecture, application, compatibility, tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, client-server, openapi, bloomberg

I'm working on a Project which aims to develop an app for a bloomberg anywhere subscriber. We have a Framework available, which we usually use to write our apps. These run ususally on a cloud as webapplications.

As apps using bloombergs open API can only run on the same machine as the subscriber is logged in biometrically, due to data acess restrictions and prohibition to distribute the data further, we plan to run our framework locally on the clients machine as a desktop application, in order to use the tools we are familiar with.

the back-end, which would use the bloomberg open api to get the data from the local interface provided by the local bloomberg-software, runs on a tomcat-server. the frontend is a javascript client, accessing the back end via API-calls locally.

My **Questions** are:

1. *As bloomberg data-access is very restrictive, i'm wondering whether the bloomberg-interface accepts calls which come from a server software (like tomcat), even when running on the same machine an not used to distribute the data further?*
2. *Would set-up: framework running on a second machine (linux, its easyer to run there), calls Bloomberg Port on first machine via private local network, data not leaving second machine, be possible 1. technically and 2. legally?*

Does anybody know that? Any advice highly appreciated, many thanks in advance!

Comment: Generally speaking the data can't leave the local machine - as long as the condition is met, you should be fine. Bloomberg monitor closely the use of the API so they may ask questions, but if your answers are satisfactory (i.e. the data doesn't leave the local machine), it should be ok. You can always ask them to get pre-approval. An alternative is to use their server API but that is an additional cost if the client doesn't already have that licence.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the quick answer! I edited the question and added a second one. would you assume this (second question) would be prohibited, or technically prevented, because - also with no further distribution, data leaving first machine? My main concern was any technical impossiblity for the first (and the second) case, but these seem then not to be the case, if i understand you correctly.

Comment: 2. seems borderline and you should probably submit your workflow to Bloomberg compliance team and get their approval - if you don't there is a risk that they may come to you in XX months and ask you to stop doing it.

Comment: All right, many thanks for your advice!